How to mount OneDrive in Ubuntu 24.04
I'm trying to connect to OneDrive in Ubuntu 24.04 which has a native Gnome 46 client. Our IT CyberSecurity team have given permission for Gnome 46, and I have followed these instructions to connect to our system. It requests my work username, password and MFA code, produces no errors, and appears to connect to OneDrive. However, on opening the OneDrive folder, instead of two folders called Shared with me and My Files, there are displayed Shared with me and root.

The Shared with Me folder contains exactly what would be expected, namely all the folders and documents that I'm collaborating with colleagues on in OneDrive.
The root folder contains a single file called __Root__.txt which contains a large amount of text that appears to point to the staff "landing page" at newcastle.sharepoint.com, rather than my own workplace OneDrive files. Note that one of the menu options on the staff landing page allows web-based access to OneDrive. First part of __Root__.txt begins:

{"sphomewebvroom:sites/recent":{"Item":{"ListItemId":55,"ListItemUniqueId":null,"CacheKey":"SPHomeWebVroom:sites/recent","AltTitle":null,"CacheValue":"{\"Items\":[{\"id\":\"newcastle.sharepoint.com,53b1fb5f-8151-4990-8560-70fd298e5447,28e16f91-b57a-4546-88b1-9dec251488e5\",\"webUrl\":\"https://newcastle.sharepoint.com/news\",\"title\":\"News\",\"sharepointIds\":{\"listItemId\":\"6012174215866472612\",\"siteId\":\"53b1fb5f-8151-4990-8560-70fd298e5447\",\"siteUrl\":\"https://newcastle.sharepoint.com/news\",\"webId\":\"28e16f91-b57a-4546-88b1-9dec251488e5\"},\"siteCollection\":{\"hostName\":\"newcastle.sharepoint.com\"},\"template\":{\"name\":\"CMSPUBLISHING\"},\"exchangeIds\":{\"id\":\"SPO_NTNiMWZiNWYtODE1MS00OTkwLTg1NjAtNzBmZDI5OGU1NDQ3LDI4ZTE2ZjkxLWI1N2EtNDU0Ni04OGIxLTlkZWMyNTE0ODhlNSwwMDAwMDAwMC0wMDAwLTAwMDAtMDAwMC0wMDAwMDAwMDAwMDA_01O2LJLRYAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\",\"documentId\":\"6012174215866472612\",\"exchangeSource\":\"Users\"},\"resourceVisualization\":{\"acronym\":\"N\",\"color\":\"#4f6bed\",\"previewImageUrl\":\"https://newcastle.sharepoint.com/SiteAssets/images/nu-shield.png\"}},{\"id\":\"newcastle.sharepoint.com,53b1fb5f-8151-4990-8560-70fd298e5447,2b01069d-1484-425f-ad6e-906ecc71365f\",\"webUrl\":\"https://newcastle.sharepoint.com/projects/Response-to-student-protest\",\"title\":\"Response to student protest\",\"sharepointIds\":{\"listItemId\":\"3495847244956161793\",\"siteId\":\"53b1fb5f-8151-4990-8560-70fd298e5447\",\"siteUrl\":\"https://newcastle.sharepoint.com/projects/Response-to-student-protest\",\"webId\":\"2b01069d-1484-425f-ad6e-906ecc71365f\"},\"siteCollection\":{\"hostName\":\"newcastle.sharepoint.com\"},\"template\":{\"name\":\"STS\"},\"exchangeIds\":{\"id\":
Unfortunately, our IT staff provide only limited Linux support, but if there is some specific resolution I can provide them it would be useful.

Are you maybe  in as root when you do this or sudo instead of your name?

I was logged in as root, as I was testing Ubuntu 24.04 by booting it from a USB. I wanted to ensure everything worked smoothly before upgrading from 22.04. However all the login to the Microsoft 365 account is based on a standard Microsoft username, password and MFA token.

You were in as root so it is working as it should. Loin with your real id and try.

Just tried again, this time with an ordinary user account setup under my username (my username is identical in Windows and Linux, but with different passwords, and Windows also uses MFA). Unfortunately I get the identical error, just seeing "Shared with me" and "root" but no sign of the "My files" folder.

I have the exact same issue and haven't found a solution. Were you able to resolve it? I seems to work fine for a Microsoft 365 Personal account, but not for my Microsoft 365 Business account.

Apparently, this issue is known and has been fixed upstream: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/msgraph/-/issues/8
